# Ansible - grab a key from a dictionary (but not in a loop)

Tags: python, yaml, ansible

Another question regarding dictionaries in Ansible!

For convenience, I have certain values for mysql databases held in dictionaries, which works fine to loop over using `with_dict` to create the DBs and DB users.

```
mysql_dbs:
  db1:
    user: db1user
    pass: "jdhfksjdf"
    accessible_from: localhost
  db2:
    user: db2user
    pass: "npoaivrpon"
    accessible_from: localhost
```

task:

```
- name: Configure mysql users
  mysql_user: name={{ item.value.user }} password={{ item.value.pass }} host={{ item.value.accessible_from }} priv={{ item.key }}.*:ALL  state=present
  with_dict: "{{ mysql_dbs }}"
```

However, I would like to use the key from one of the dictionaries in another task, but I don't want to loop over the dictionaries, I would only like to use one at a time. How would I grab the key that describes the dictionary (sorry, not sure about terminology)?

problem task:

```
- name: Add the db1 schema
  shell: mysql {{ item }} < /path/to/db1.sql 
  with_items: '{{ mysql_dbs[db1] }}'
```

Error in ansible run:

```
fatal: [myhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'item' is undefined"}
```

I'm willing to believe `with_items` isn't the best strategy here, but does anyone have any ideas what is the right one?

Thanks in advance, been stuck on this for a while now...

Comment: I think you accidentally deleted part of your question?  I am referring to the mysterious empty space after "I've tried".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given a nested dictionary...

```
mysql_dbs:
  db1:
    user: db1user
    pass: "jdhfksjdf"
    accessible_from: localhost
  db2:
    user: db2user
    pass: "npoaivrpon"
    accessible_from: localhost
```

You can either use dotted notation:

```
- debug:
    var: mysql_dbs.db1
```

Or you can use a more Python-esque syntax:

```
- debug:
    var: mysql_dbs['db1']
```

It looks like you tried to use an unholy hybrid:

```
mysql_dbs[db1]
```

In this case, you are trying to dereference a variable named `db1`,
which presumably doesn't exist and would lead to a "variable is
undefined" sort of error.

**Update**

Your question is unclear because in your example you have...

```
with_items: '{{ mysql_dbs[db1] }}'
```

...which looks like you are trying to do exactly what I have described here.  If what you actually want to do is iterate over the keys of the `mysql_dbs` dictionary, remember that it is simply a Python dictionary and you have available all the standard dictionary methods, so:

```
- debug:
    msg: "key: {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ mysql_dbs.keys() }}"
```

The output of which would be:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=db1) => {
    "item": "db1", 
    "msg": "key: db1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=db2) => {
    "item": "db2", 
    "msg": "key: db2"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to give me the values from the dictionary:

`{u'accessible_from': u'localhost', u'user': u'db1user', u'pass': u'jdhfksjdf'}"`, is there any way to grab the key?

Comment: Sure. Just add another dot; I hoped that was obvious:  `mysql_dbs.db1.user`, `mysql_dbs.db2.pass`, etc.  Or, alternatively, `mysql_dbs['db1']['user']`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made the question clear enough - I would like to render e.g. `db1` or `db2`, rather than the values in the dictionary: `user`, `pass` or `accessible_from`. Is that posssible?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the done thing, but thanks for persevering with me, that worked! :)

Comment: `remember that it is simply a Python dictionary and you have available all the standard dictionary methods` just what I needed to hear. Thanks.

Comment: `remember that it is simply a Python dictionary and you have available all the standard dictionary methods` ! Same for me: I needed to get a value from a dictionary, but the dictionary was i a list with 1 element: `{{ ansible_facts.packages.samba4[0].version }}`